# Why is there a space above blue box?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create some divs; but after putting two divs side by side, next div has space before it. It should not be there.

Why is the space before blue div there? Check image, I cannot add image directly due to lower rep.

Is there a better way do draw that layout?

I am a beginner.

OUTPUT

[Image of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnQNM.png)

```css
div {
  color: green;
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  border: thin solid #333;
}

#redbox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#yellowbox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}

#greenbox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

#bluebox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>GOOGLE</div>
<div id="redbox"></div>
<div id="yellowbox"></div>
<div id="greenbox"></div>
<div id="bluebox"></div>
```

Comment: because inline-block stands on baseline by defaut. reset their vertical-align to top or bottom to hide that gap used by text (jpqgy...)

Comment: It worked! https://jsfiddle.net/jsgirl/5addf24v/6/ Can you please explain more?

Comment: See https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align to see what values it takes and where inline elements stands by defaut.

Answer (score 3):

because `inline-block` stands on baseline by defaut just like the text does.

See : https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

> The vertical-align property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of the boxes generated by an inline-level element.
>
> **Description**
>
> **Values**        `baseline | sub | super | top | text-top | middle | bottom | text-bottom | <percentage> | <length> | inherit` .
>
> **Initial value**     baseline
>
> **Applies to**     inline-level and 'table-cell'
>
> **elements Inherited**     No

So if you reset their `vertical-align` to `top` or `bottom` it will erase  that gap used by text needed for letters such as `g j p q y` .

You might also want to read about [line-height](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height) (default value  is average set by font-size X 1.2 = 1.2em)

```css
div {
  color: green;
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  border: thin solid #333;
}

#redbox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#yellowbox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

#greenbox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

#bluebox {
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>GOOGLE</div>
<div id="redbox"></div>
<div id="yellowbox"></div>
<div id="greenbox"></div>
<div id="bluebox"></div>
```

i used top and bottom, it works fine because each boxes have same height , best is to use one or the other